# Deleting Row from UISearchResults filtered list using Realm

Tags: swift, uitableview, realm, uisearchcontroller

I am using Realm as my back end data store and I have a tableview with a UISearchResults controller.
If I am not filtering the result, I have no problem deleting a row from the tableView and removing it from my Realm database.
However, when I filter using the SearchController and try to swipe delete the row, I get the error.

> reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The
>   number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2)
>   must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before
>   the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted
>   from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number
>   of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Here is my function that I use when filtering my locations

```
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
        filteredLocations  = locations.filter { location in
            return location.site.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

And this is my tableView delete function

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
            if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
                // This is from a filtered list
                do {
                    try realm.write() {
                        self.realm.delete(filteredLocations[indexPath.row])
                    }
                   tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

                } catch {
                    print("Could not delete site")
                }
            } else {
                do {
                    try realm.write() {
                        self.realm.delete(locations[indexPath.row])
                    }
                    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
                } catch {
                    print("Could not delete site")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me to sort this out?

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this issue for a ridiculous amount of time. It's been a while since this question was asked, but for future folks maybe this can help. I don't know Realm but for those using Core Data I found that all I needed to do was reload the tableview in the fetchedResultsController didChangeObject method for deletions and updates.

For example:

```
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    switch type {
        case .Insert:
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        case .Delete:

            if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
                tableView.reloadData()//THIS
            } else {
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            }//if else

        case .Update:

            if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
                tableView.reloadData()//AND THIS
            } else {
                self.configureCell(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)!, atIndexPath: indexPath!)
            }//if else

        case .Move:
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
}//controller:didChangeObject
```

Answer (score 0):

That error message occurs in `UITableView` if you attempt to delete a cell without completely removing the equivalent object from the data source first. The fact that the error message is saying `section after the update (2)` and not `(1)` seems to imply that your data source is still hanging on to a reference to the item you just deleted from Realm.

From the looks of it, since you're manually generating the contents of `filteredObjects` yourself, you'll probably need to manually delete the entry from it as well, after you've deleted it from Realm, but before you call the `UITableView` cell deletion method.

```
if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
    // This is from a filtered list
    do {
        try realm.write() {
            self.realm.delete(filteredLocations[indexPath.row])
        }
        filteredLocations.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    } catch {
        print("Could not delete site")
    }
}
```

I'm guessing it's working fine normally, as `locations` would most likely be a `Results` object from Realm, which will automatically update itself to remove the item after you instructed Realm to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, the problem was actually nothing to do with the Realm object removal. It was related to the tableview rows count being different after the object was removed. I was able to put an if check on the search controller and determine if I needed to run .deleteRowsAtIndexPaths. That fixed my crash but then the search results wouldn't update to reflect the removed object. It would just hang. A call to .searchResultsUpdater fixed that. Not sure if it will help but the code from my app is below. Do note I use a helper class to do all my Realm functions, and I reload my data source array after the row delete.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {

        var studentToDelete = Student()

        if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != ""{
            studentToDelete = filteredStudents[indexPath.row]
            DBhelper.deleteByName(studentToDelete.name)
            students = DBhelper.getAllObjetcs()
            searchController.searchResultsUpdater?.updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController)

        }else{
            studentToDelete = students[indexPath.row]
            DBhelper.deleteByName(studentToDelete.name)
            students = DBhelper.getAllObjetcs()
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }


    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
}
```